# Why does my reference type object have 3 strong references right after initialization?

Tags: swift, xcode, lldb

I have a pretty simple class:

```swift
class TestClass {}
```

then I created an instance of this class:

```swift
let instance = TestClass()
```

After that I started my project (debug build) and ran command in Xcode console:

```
language swift refcount instance
```

and what I got was:

> refcount data: (strong = 3, unowned = 1, weak = 1)

I wonder why my instance has 3 strong references, 1 unowned and 1 weak, if in fact there is only 1 strong reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason `language swift refcount instance` is showing 3 strong references is probably because of retaining your instance inside of debug code. Moreover, if you will repeat the command, you will get incrementing results:

```
(lldb) language swift refcount instance
refcount data: (strong = 3, unowned = 1, weak = 1)
(lldb) language swift refcount instance
refcount data: (strong = 4, unowned = 1, weak = 1)
(lldb) language swift refcount instance
refcount data: (strong = 5, unowned = 1, weak = 1)
```

I think this is kind of Xcode/runtime bug.

Also, [you can use](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1521288-cfgetretaincount) `CFGetRetainCount` to check reference count on an instance:

```swift
let instance = TestClass()
print(CFGetRetainCount(instance)) // prints "2"
```

The reason you get "2" is `instance` is retained by `let instance` static variable, as well as it is retained inside the `CFGetRetainCount` function. You can proof this by calling

```
print(CFGetRetainCount(TestClass())) // prints "1"
```

Comment: I wonder if this is a bug, or if the debugger itself is forming new strong references, and that's what's being counted

Comment: @Alexander Debugger is forming strong references and this really looks like a leak to me. Especially the fact that references are kept until the process is dead.